# How to unselect elements in PageLayoutControl (using C#)

Tags: arcobjects, c#, arcgis-9.3

I have a PagelayoutControl with the name: PageControl. And I added a text element into MapFrame (FocusMap) of the PagelayoutControl. If the text element and MapFrame are selected (by using the button "Select Elements" on the toolbar).

Do you know are there any ways to unselect the elements and MapFrame by using code in C# ?

Please see my screenshots (in cases: selected and unselected)

[image]

[image]

Thanks and regards,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

QI from [`IMapFrame.Map`](http://resources.esri.com/help/9.3/arcgisengine/ArcObjects/ao_start.htm#esricarto/IMapFrame_Map.htm) to [`IGraphicsContainerSelect`](http://resources.esri.com/help/9.3/arcgisengine/ArcObjects/ao_start.htm#esricarto/IGraphicsContainerSelect.htm) and call its [`UnselectAllElements`](http://resources.esri.com/help/9.3/arcgisengine/ArcObjects/ao_start.htm#esricarto/IGraphicsContainerSelect_UnselectAllElements.htm) or [`UnselectElement`](http://resources.esri.com/help/9.3/arcgisengine/ArcObjects/ao_start.htm#esricarto/IGraphicsContainerSelect_UnselectAllElements.htm) methods.

Comment: Thank you. But when elements are selecting. I can't find the MapFrame object of PageLayoutControl. I use the statement: IElement pElement = graphicsContainer.Next(); to find elements. (with graphicsContainer = pageControl.ActiveView.GraphicsContainer;)

Comment: Hi blah238. I can do now, I used another statement : graphicsContainer = PageControl.PageLayout as IGraphicsContainer